# Split text without separating e.g. 'New York'

Tags: python

I know how to split a string into a list of words, like this:

```
some_string = "Siva is belongs to new York and he was living in park meadows mall apartment "
some_string.split()
# ['Siva', 'is', 'belongs', 'to', 'new', 'York', 'and', 'he', 'was', living', 'in', 'park', 'meadows', 'mall', 'apartment']
```

**However**, some of the words should not be separated, for example, "New York" and "Park Meadows Mall". I have saved such special cases in a list called ´some_list´:

```
some_list = [('new York'), ('park meadows mall')]
```

where the desired result would be:

```
['Siva', 'is', 'belongs', 'to', 'new York', 'and', 'he', 'was', living', 'in', 'park meadows mall', 'apartment']
```

Any ideas on how I can get this done?

Comment: but i want new york is single word

Comment: You presented the problem cleanly, but you also need to provide what you have tried so far (or at least that's what I guess the downvote came from)

Comment: Does your actual ``some_list`` contain overlapping elements, such as ``new York`` and ``new Orleans``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reconstruct the splitted elements into their compound form. Ideally, you want to scan over your splitted string only once, checking each element against all possible replacements.

A naive approach is too transform `some_list` into a lookup table for all possible sequences given *one* word. For example, the element `'new'` indicates a potential replacement for `'new', 'York'`. Such a table can be built by splitting off the first word of each compound word:

```
replacements = {}
for compound in some_list:
    words = compound.split()  # 'new York' => 'new', 'York'
    try:                      # 'new' => [('new', 'York'), ('new', 'Orleans')]
        replacements[words[0]] = [words]
    except KeyError:          # 'new' => [('new', 'York')]
        replacements[words[0]].append(words)
```

Using this, you can traverse your splitted string and test for each word whether it might be part of a compound word. The tricky part is to avoid adding trailing parts of compound words.

```
splitted_string = some_string.split()
compound_string = []
insertion_offset = 0
for index, word in enumerate(splitted_string):
    # we already added a compound string, skip its members
    if len(compound_string) + insertion_offset > index:
        continue
    # check if a compound word starts here...
    try:
        candidate_compounds = replacements[word]
    except KeyError:
        # definitely not, just keep the word
        compound_string.append(word)
    else:
        # try all possible compound words...
        for compound in candidate_compounds:
            if splitted_string[index:index+len(compound)] == compound:
                insertion_offset += len(compound)
                compound_string.append(' '.join(compound))
                break
        # ...but otherwise, just keep the word
        else:
            compound_string.append(word)
```

This will stitch together all individual pieces of compound words:

```
 >>> print(compound_string)
 ['Siva', 'is', 'belongs', 'to', 'new York', 'he', 'was', 'living', 'in', 'park meadows mall']
```

---

Note that the ideal structure of the `replacements` table depends on your words in `some_list`. If there are no collisions of first words, you can skip the list of compound word*s* and have only one compound word each. If there are many collisions, you may have to nest several tables inside to avoid having to try all candidates. The later is especially important if `some_string` is large.